# Swift "Could not cast value of type "AppName.ToDoViewViewCtonroller" to AppName.CalendarView" SIGBART

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to create an app which logs the cell of the current calendar day accordingly to a selected color. I had that portion working but then I added another UIViewController named " ToDoViewViewController" and when I try to go from the main ViewController to that one (with the touch of a button) I get the error "Could not cast value of type "AppName.ToDoViewViewCtonroller" to AppName.CalendarView " and Thread 1 SIGBART which takes me to a line that says:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let DestViewControler: CalendarView = segue.destination as! CalendarView
        DestViewControler.color = [selectedMood] //selected mood reflects color for cell
    }
```

I tried to comment that out and then the segue from the main view controller to the ToDoViewViewControler works perfectly fine, but then the colors of the cell do not change.

What is this error? I am very new to swift(self taught) and can't seem to figure this out.

Comment: Your destination view controller for the segue is a `ToDoViewController` not a `CalendarView`, so the forced downcast (`as!`) causes an exception

Comment: If you're trying to go to the `ToDoViewViewController`, you seem to have succeeded.  The problem is that you're claiming it will be a `CalendarView`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your viewController in prepareForSegue method with the actual viewController class name of it, what you do is wrong, as you try to cast a view controller into a UIView. I believe what you try to do is, change the color of ToDoVC with segue, try this:

First have a UIColor variable inside your ToDoViewViewCtonroller as:

```
class ToDoViewViewCtonroller {

    var color: UIColor!

}
```

Then update your `prepareForSegue` as following:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let destinationVC = segue.destination as! ToDoViewViewCtonroller
    destinationVC.color = UIColor.red //set the color to a value here I wrote UIColor.red for an example.
}
```

Then again inside your ToDoViewViewCtonroller, maybe in viewDidLoad method set your containerView's backgroundColor to your color:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    containerView.backgroundColor = color
}
```